# What is C++ translation for Matlabs `fread(fp, 1, 'int32')` and fread(fp, n, 'uchar')

Tags: c++, matlab, file-io, translation, fread

So I try to convert such Matlab code to C++:

```
ss = 'file.mask'
fp = fopen(ss, 'rb');
sx = fread(fp,  1, 'int32')
sy = fread(fp,  1, 'int32')
mask = zeros(sy, sx);
mm = mask(100, 100:200);
count = zeros(10, 1); 
for i = 1:sy
    row = fread(fp,  sx, 'uchar');
    for j = 1:sx
        for k = 1:10
            if row(j) == k - 1
                count(k) = count(k) + 1;
            end
        end
    end
    mask(i, :) = row;
end
fclose(fp);
```

And so I wonder what is C++ analog of Matlab `fread`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want a C++ analog and not a C analog (or even a C/C++ analog), then you should rather use `std::ifstream`:

```
std::ifstream in("file.mask", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);

int sx, sy;
in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&sx), sizeof(int));
in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&sy), sizeof(int));
std::vector<unsigned char> row(sx);

for(...)
{
    ...
    in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&row[0]), sx);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Will `in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&row[0]), sx);` read all contents of one mask  row into  `vector`?

Comment: @Kabumbus Yes, as long as `sx` is the size in bytes of a row (and you don't read across the end of file or other erroneous behaviour). In fact you could also do `if(!in.read(...)) handle error;`, but you don't do that in your MATLAB code either.

Answer (score 2):

`std::fstream` is the C++ standard (with no other libraries than the standard one) of accessing files. It provides `operator>>`, which is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: If he wants to read it binary, then `operator>>` is not much of use, I think. But I agree that he should use `std::fstream`, which also provides a `read` method.

Comment: Well, `operator>>` maybe not, but there is still `read` you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

`std::fstream` is the standard in c++ and that is certainly what you should use.

However, `fread` and `fclose` are standard C function and thus can be used in C++.

Answer (score 0):

fread exists in C, which is not commonly used in C++. However, if you want something pretty close, you can do the following.

```
sx=fread(fp,  1, 'int32') is

int sx;
fread(&sx, sizeof(int), 1, fp);

row = fread(fp,  sx, 'uchar'); is

unsigned char row;
fread(&row, sizeof(unsigned char), sx, fp);
```

If you need to read and parse textually represented numbers, you can use fscanf with C IO functions.

Edit:

Fixed the size in the second conversion.

Comment: It's less convenient than `fstream`, IMHO.

Comment: Considering he wanted the C++ analog, this is not really a good answer. And your analog to the second function call is wrong anyway, as he wants to read the whole row and not just a char.

Comment: my offer is convinient and cstdlib is still there. streams would be new concept for a matlab programmer.